# Is it possible for a field to be read-only in the metadata, but update-able in a layout?

Tags: rest-api, metadata, page-layout

Using the REST API (v31.0), I can get the metadata for an object and look at the fields for that object.

```
{
 fields: [
    {
       ...
       updateable: false,
     }
  ]
}
```

Buried deep within the `detailLayoutSections` and `editLayoutSections` for an object, the `details` object will also have an `updateable` flag.

This has made me wonder if it is possible to have a field be non-updateable in the metadata, but updateable in a layout (since you can choose on the layout if a field should be read-only or not).

Answer (score 5):

I would say no.

The reason for the updateable in the layout is that a field can be updateable at the object level BUT be set to read only on the layout and thus not updateable. Unless I am misunderstanding your question.